# How to convert 2 column HTML table to 3 column

Tags: html, html-table, dreamweaver

I'm very new to HTML. I have an HTML document that is built using a 2 column table. I am now needing to set up a row with 3 columns. From the research that I've done, it seems that I can't just add a column to 1 row, rather I need to work with a 3 column table and use colspan in the other rows to make things work. Is that correct?

I've tried adjusting the existing colspans from =2 to =3 and adding a new column to the desired row but to no avail. Can you tell me what is wrong with my approach or how to properly convert the existing 2 column table to a 3 column structure?

```
<table width="768" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #000000" >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="768" height="160" border="0" style="display:inline" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="256"></td>
        <td width="256"></td>
        <td width="256"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post your `HTML`. Are you using the `<table>` for layout purposes, or for `tabular` data?

Comment: I wouldn´t recommend using tables for layout, that is considered a bad practice. But the answer would be adding a <td> tag inside each <tr> or <th>. <td> represents a column in html

Comment: Please note that tables are not for setting a layout,  you must use divs (or html5 tags) for this

Comment: The code has been added to the original post. Basically I'm just trying to achieve a 3-column structure where each column is 256px wide and I can use colspan across the others to meet the layout requirements. I'm working off an old document which may be part of the problem.

Comment: You haven't close a lot of td tag.

Comment: If you are trying to re-create a layout using `<table>s`, stop right there... :) Use divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr> <!-- row with 3 columns -->
        <td>1x1</td>
        <td>1x2</td>
        <td>1x3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- row with only 2 columns, where the second column is as wide as the second and third column, above -->
        <td>2x1</td>
        <td colspan="2">2x2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is how to get a table with N rows and 3 columns. Is it what you were asking for? It would be useful if you could paste some code!

See this page to learn more about colspan:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

EDIT:

In your code you have written the table to display only 2 columns for every row.
You have to add a `<td>` tag to display another column per row.

Comment: So are you saying that betweeen each of the table row tags, there needs to be 3 <td></td> tags for the 3-column structure to work?

Comment: Yes, instead of this you would see a third column where specified and an empty space where not.

Comment: That was exactly my problem, thank you. Between your reply and the link you provided, I was able to get it working.